# javascript: React - adding an array to an object changes the format of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new at React. I have an array of objects that I created from the values of a Form. When I print it in the console it looks fine. but when I try to add that array to a different object, it changes its format in a very strange way.
Here's the code:

```
const [ingredientes, setIngredientes] = useState([]);

const loadIngredient= (value) => {ingredients.push(value); setIngredients(ingredients);}



const LoadIngredient= () => {
        loadIngredient(JSON.stringify({ingredient: ingredient, cant: parseInt(cantidad,10), unit: unidad}));
        console.log('ingredients loaded: ', ingredients)
    }

const RegistrarProducto = () => {

    alert('Producto registrado: '+ JSON.stringify({
      name: name,
      image: image,
      description: description,
      receta: receta,
      ingredients:ingredients}));
  }
```

this is how it looks:

Producto registrado:

```
{"name":"Cookies","image":"","description":"The best cookies ever","receta":"this is a test only","ingredients":["{\"ingredient\":\"mantequilla\",\"cant\":100,\"unit\":\"gramos\"}","{\"ingredient\":\"azucar\",\"cant\":300,\"unit\":\"gramos\"}","{\"ingredient\":\"harina\",\"cant\":1,\"unit\":\"tazas\"}"]}
```

[Producto Registrado Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFSnZ.png)

Can somebody explain to me why that happens? Thanks in advance and sorry for the spanglish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is a serialized format of the JSON, since you use `JSON.stringify()` before passing value to `loadIngredient`

If you want it to be an object inside your state array, just remove the usage of `JSON.stringify`

```
const LoadIngredient= () => {
    loadIngredient({ingredient: ingredient, cant: parseInt(cantidad,10), unit: unidad});
    console.log('ingredients loaded: ', ingredients)
}
```

Comment: I get it, that was it! Thank you so much!